# FOSUserBundle generate:entities does not work, Access level of fields too high

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

I have a problem with FOSUserBundle after I configured DoctrineExtensions, with StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle.

First of all, to install DoctrineExtensions I had to remove "auto_mapping: true" segment from app/config/config.yml file.

I found that if auto_mapping is not active I have to include FOSUserBundle: ~ in default:mappings segment.

But, when I try

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

or

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities FOS
```

I get:

```
PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/ming.ini on line 1 in Unknown on line 0
Generating entities for namespace "FOS"
PHP Fatal error:  Access level to FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User::$username must be protected (as in class FOS\UserBundle\Model\User) or weaker in /var/www/rBay/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/Entity/User.php on line 17
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/rBay/app/console:0
PHP   2. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() /var/www/rBay/app/console:22
PHP   3. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() /var/www/rBay/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:105
PHP   4. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() /var/www/rBay/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:78
PHP   5. Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() /var/www/rBay/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:192
PHP   6. Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Command\GenerateEntitiesDoctrineCommand->execute() /var/www/rBay/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:238
PHP   7. Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Mapping\MetadataFactory->getNamespaceMetadata() /var/www/rBay/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/Doctrine/Bundle/DoctrineBundle/Command/GenerateEntitiesDoctrineCommand.php:109
PHP   8. Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Mapping\MetadataFactory->getMetadataForNamespace() /var/www/rBay/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/Doctrine/Bundle/DoctrineBundle/Mapping/MetadataFactory.php:97
PHP   9. Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Mapping\MetadataFactory->getAllMetadata() /var/www/rBay/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/Doctrine/Bundle/DoctrineBundle/Mapping/MetadataFactory.php:160
PHP  10. Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getAllMetadata() /var/www/rBay/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/Doctrine/Bundle/DoctrineBundle/Mapping/MetadataFactory.php:196
PHP  11. Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\MappingDriverChain->getAllClassNames() /var/www/rBay/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:111
PHP  12. Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver->getAllClassNames() /var/www/rBay/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/Driver/MappingDriverChain.php:132
PHP  13. require_once() /var/www/rBay/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/Driver/AnnotationDriver.php:194
PHP  14. Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\DebugClassLoader->loadClass() /var/www/rBay/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/DebugClassLoader.php:0
PHP  15. require() /var/www/rBay/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/DebugClassLoader.php:82

Fatal error: Access level to FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User::$username must be protected (as in class FOS\UserBundle\Model\User) or weaker in /var/www/rBay/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/Entity/User.php on line 17

Call Stack:
0.0002     644752   1. {main}() /var/www/rBay/app/console:0
0.0132    3467080   2. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() /var/www/rBay/app/console:22
0.0155    3851816   3. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() /var/www/rBay/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:105
2.3154   50066792   4. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() /var/www/rBay/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:78
2.3187   50066792   5. Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() /var/www/rBay/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:192
2.3192   50068328   6. Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Command\GenerateEntitiesDoctrineCommand->execute() /var/www/rBay/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:238
2.3208   50178008   7. Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Mapping\MetadataFactory->getNamespaceMetadata() /var/www/rBay/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/Doctrine/Bundle/DoctrineBundle/Command/GenerateEntitiesDoctrineCommand.php:109
2.3208   50178008   8. Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Mapping\MetadataFactory->getMetadataForNamespace() /var/www/rBay/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/Doctrine/Bundle/DoctrineBundle/Mapping/MetadataFactory.php:97
2.3208   50178320   9. Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Mapping\MetadataFactory->getAllMetadata() /var/www/rBay/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/Doctrine/Bundle/DoctrineBundle/Mapping/MetadataFactory.php:160
2.3307   50203984  10. Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getAllMetadata() /var/www/rBay/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/Doctrine/Bundle/DoctrineBundle/Mapping/MetadataFactory.php:196
2.3308   50204456  11. Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\MappingDriverChain->getAllClassNames() /var/www/rBay/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:111
2.3308   50205408  12. Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver->getAllClassNames() /var/www/rBay/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/Driver/MappingDriverChain.php:132
2.3428   52000872  13. require_once('/var/www/rBay/src/MSoft/UserBundle/Entity/User.php') /var/www/rBay/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/Driver/AnnotationDriver.php:194
2.3428   52001400  14. Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\DebugClassLoader->loadClass() /var/www/rBay/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/DebugClassLoader.php:0
2.3431   52081336  15. require('/var/www/rBay/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/Entity/User.php') /var/www/rBay/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/DebugClassLoader.php:82
```

I'll attach related regions of my config file, as well, just in case...

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    driver:   %database_driver%
    host:     %database_host%
    port:     %database_port%
    dbname:   %database_name%
    user:     %database_user%
    password: %database_password%
    charset:  UTF8

orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
    entity_managers:
        default:
            connection: default
            mappings:
                gedmo_translatable:
                    type: annotation
                    prefix: Gedmo\Translatable\Entity
                    dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Translatable/Entity"
                    alias: GedmoTranslatable # this one is optional and will default to the name set for the mapping
                    is_bundle: false
                gedmo_translator:
                    type: annotation
                    prefix: Gedmo\Translator\Entity
                    dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Translator/Entity"
                    alias: GedmoTranslator # this one is optional and will default to the name set for the mapping
                    is_bundle: false
                gedmo_loggable:
                    type: annotation
                    prefix: Gedmo\Loggable\Entity
                    dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Loggable/Entity"
                    alias: GedmoLoggable # this one is optional and will default to the name set for the mapping
                    is_bundle: false
                gedmo_tree:
                    type: annotation
                    prefix: Gedmo\Tree\Entity
                    dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Tree/Entity"
                    alias: GedmoTree # this one is optional and will default to the name set for the mapping
                    is_bundle: false
                MSoftAdminBundle: ~
                MSoftUserBundle: ~
                FOSUserBundle: ~

# Fosuser Configuration
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: MSoft\UserBundle\Entity\User

stof_doctrine_extensions:
    default_locale: en_US
    orm:
        default:
            tree: true
            sluggable: true
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Solved. Problem appeared when I ran

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities FOS
```

Than doctrine entity generator added properties that wasn't supposed to be there, and that made a problem.
The point is that class FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User should have empty body, and generator created all the fields from FOS\UserBundle\Model\User in it, just with higher protection level ("private" instead of "protected").

Answer (score 1):

All properties of the User class should be protected, not public.

Comment: But these are properties that I didn't set.
"Access level to FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User::$username must be protected (as in class FOS\UserBundle\Model\User) or weaker in /var/www/rBay/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/Entity/User.php on line 17"